# Get Startpage to label tabs with search query

Tags: startpage

When Startpage opens a page with search results the tab for the new page is labeled beginning with "Search results - Startpage" where the label fades out on the right hand side.

Whereas when I open search with DuckDuckGo or Google the search terms are listed in the tab label first.

After several search in Startpage I lose track of what search window is which search since the tabs all look the same, but with the other browsers it's easy to tell.

When I look at Startpage example searches as on this page:

http://securityspread.com/2016/10/24/duckduckgo-startpage-2016-update/

they show the tabs labeled as in Google and DuckDuckGo but I can't find any way to display them this way in the Startpage options.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Sadly it turns out Startpage doesn't have the capability for the search query to be displayed. I sent them a support request with the same question and got this reply:

> Thanks for getting in touch with us about this feature and I'm sorry not having titles in the tabs is inconvenient.
>
> The reason we don't have different identifying terms in the search query in the page title in the browser bar tabs is because we consider your information private and we use a generic URL so your browser won't know what you are searching.

Comment: I think that's a weird reason, but it should be possible to do it dynamically using a "UserScript".

Comment: Added an [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153276/199876) with a  UserScript to archive this.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with a one-linear "[user script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript)", changing the page/tab title dynamically based on the search result. [This](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/424498-startpage-com-search-result-on-page-title) user script can be utilized to archive the desired behavior:

```
document.title = `${document.getElementById('q').value} - Startpage.com`;
```